# How to make an id= from an XML call give a link to what its calling?

Tags: ajax, youtube, href

One of my API calls gives a youtube link and I want the link to be clickable and open on another tab, but nothing is working

this is mode code HTML:

//the id produces a youtube link that that can be clicked, but if I add the id to the href, then it wont work.

```
<a href="" target="_blank">
<p id="strYoutube2"></p>
</a>
```

my js code:

//this is my XML call, if theres another .link function other than .innerXML for the youtube link, maybe that can be the issue, but I cant find anything online.
function getPosts() {

```
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php', true);
  console.log(xhr.readyState);

  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log('response below:')
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.meals[0].strMealThumb);
      document.getElementById('strMeal').innerText = response.meals[0].strMeal
      document.getElementById('strCategory').innerText = response.meals[0].strCategory
      document.getElementById('strArea').innerText = response.meals[0].strArea
      document.getElementById('strTags').innerText = response.meals[0].strTags
      document.getElementById('strYoutube').innerHTML = response.meals[0].strYoutube
      document.getElementById('strMealThumb').src = response.meals[0].strMealThumb
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *the id produces a youtube link that that can be clicked, but if I add the id to the href, then it wont work.* you should [edit] to show the output you say "wont work" as well as an exact description of how it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element with id `strYoutube` does NOT exist in you provided code:

```
document.getElementById('strYoutube').innerHTML = response.meals[0].strYoutube
```

For achieve what you're triyng to do, you can change your code as follows:

Check that I set an `img` HTML element with a predefined `width` and `height`.

Check the [working jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/hfng9uds/) too:

```js
// This is your function for get the posts of the given API URL.
function getPosts() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php', true);
  console.log(xhr.readyState);

  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log('response below:')
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.meals[0].strMealThumb);

      // Comented due these HTML elements aren't here.
      //document.getElementById('strMeal').innerText = response.meals[0].strMeal
      //document.getElementById('strCategory').innerText = response.meals[0].strCategory
      //document.getElementById('strArea').innerText = response.meals[0].strArea
      //document.getElementById('strTags').innerText = response.meals[0].strTags
      //document.getElementById('strYoutube').innerHTML = response.meals[0].strYoutube
      //document.getElementById('strMealThumb').src = response.meals[0].strMealThumb

      // Here I set the values to your HTML elements:
      // "strYoutube" is the HTML anchor element "<a href>".
      document.getElementById('strYoutube').href = response.meals[0].strYoutube;

      // "myImg" is the HTML image element "<img src>".
      document.getElementById('myImg').src = "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/ysqupp1511640538.jpg";
      document.getElementById('myImg').alt = response.meals[0].strMeal;
      document.getElementById('myImg').title = response.meals[0].strMeal;
    }
  }
}

// Call your function and set the values ion the HTML elements:
getPosts();
```

```html
<a href="" target="_blank" id="strYoutube">
  <p id="strYoutube2">
    <img src="#" id="myImg" alt="image" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
  </p>
</a>
```